# Why did the contract writer use both provision and term?

Tags: contract-law, international, legal-terms, sale-of-goods

This is a provision in  CONTRACT FOR THE
INTERNATIONAL COMMERCIAL
SALE OF GOODS

12. Effects of avoidance in general

12.1 Avoidance of this contract releases both parties from their obligation to
effect and to receive future performance, subject to any damages that may be
due.

12.2 Avoidance of this contract does not preclude a claim for damages for
non-performance.

12.3 Avoidance of this contract does not affect any **provision** in this contract
for the settlement of disputes or any other **term** of this contract that is to
operate even after avoidance.

I cannot get why the writer used "provision" and "term" at the same time here. I thought in contracts, we'd have to use only one word throughout the whole thing to avoid misunderstandings

Comment: Why do you care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did the contract writer use both provision and term?

Generally speaking, the usage of either or both terms is inconsequential. It does not alter the meaning of the contract.

> I thought in contracts, we'd have to use only one word throughout the whole thing to avoid misunderstandings

There is no rule, requirement, or habit to that effect. A contract can be clear despite using synonyms. Conversely, sticking to only one term in the entire contract does not preclude flaws or ambiguities in the semantics.